# Windows stop a services when I start it

Tags: windows-10, services

I have windows 10 with all the updates.

Today I have noticed some strange behavior :
I found that a service was not running. when I start it, automatically it is stopped. Also in services.msc I tested it, but I faced the same problem.
I did'nt get any error. It is a license manager software. it must be run.
My Windows was updated yesterday and I faced this problem

This problem appears only to some services that are related to applications ( not those that are system services ). These services don't depend on any other service.

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to be more specific. Do you get any errors or is anything not working properly? What services exhibit this behaviour? Also, not all services need to be running all the time. Many are only started on demand, so there may be nothing wrong.

Comment: No, I did'nt get any error. It is a license manager software. it must be run.
My Windows was updated yesterday and I faced this problem.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include this information? Also, is there anything in your Windows logs that might point to a cause? Have you tried to reinstall the application?

Comment: I did'nt check it. No, I can't reinstall it.